# Как убрать верхний отступ у блока text?

Tags: css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#text {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#one,
#two,
#tree {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

#text {
    
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main">
    <section id="section"><!--
        --><div id="one"></div><!--
        --><div id ="two"></div><!--
        --><div id="tree"></div><!--
    --></section>
    <section id="text">
        <p>aksdkasdlasdlasdad</p>
    </section>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Вы же `#section` устанавливаете `height: 300px;`. Поменяйте просто значение, или напишите подробнее что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Да увидел спасибо. Тут просто уже мозги закипают

Comment: `#text p {  line-height: normal; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы для блока с `id="text"` дали стиль `line-height: 80px;`.

Вот я убрал это. Но если это вам все таки необходимо то надо тегу `p` что лежит в нем дать другой `line-height`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#text {
  width: 100%;
  //line-height: 80px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#one,
#two,
#tree {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

#text {
    
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <section id="section"><!--
        --><div id="one"></div><!--
        --><div id ="two"></div><!--
        --><div id="tree"></div><!--
    --></section>
    <section id="text">
        <p>aksdkasdlasdlasdad</p>
    </section>
</div>
```